# How can I calculate this equation if we know that there is non zero Berry-phase between the valence and conduction band

Tags: quantum-spin, dielectric, topological-insulators, berry-pancharatnam-phase, bloch-sphere

The geometric phase can be interpreted as a Berry curvature in the momentum space. My guess is $(q^2+\text{Berry-phase}/\text{lattice constant}^2)/\text{direct gap}$.

$$\langle\psi_{n',\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q}}^{(0)}|e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}}|\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}^{(0)}\rangle
=\frac{1}{v}\int_vu_{n',\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q}}^*(\mathbf{r})u_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$

Comment: I'm not understanding. LHS seems to depend on  ${\bf r}$, but RHS has the ${\bf r}$ integrated over. Should he $r$ on the LHS be the operator $\hat {\bf r}$? Id so should there be an exponential on the RHS also? It's probably obvious but a little help here...

Comment: A fair observation, ψ(r)_{n′,k+q}^{0} depends on r, since the Bloch function is in the zeroth order of the perturbation calculation. The expression can be written in the form q^2/direct-gap if the interaction between electrons can be ignored, i.e. the Bloch-Hamilton operator can be written in the following form: H = -ħ^2 / (2m) ∇^2 + V